# How can I create a union type for a tree, where it takes 'a type of key and 'b type of value in OCaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I wish to create a `bst` (binary search tree) union type.

It is either `leaf` or `node`. For node, it takes `'a` key and `'b` value.

I did this:

```
type 'a*'b bst = 
  | Node of 'a * 'b * ('a*'b) bst * ('a*'b) bst
  | Leaf;;
```

but it doesn't work

**How should I do it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for multi-parameter polymorphic types is the following:

```
type ('a, 'b) bst = 
  | Node of 'a * 'b * ('a, 'b) bst * ('a, 'b) bst
  | Leaf;;
```

Answer (score 4):

The syntax you are looking for is:

```
# type ('a, 'b) bst =                              
      | Node of 'a * 'b * ('a,'b) bst * ('a,'b) bst
      | Leaf;;                                     
type ('a, 'b) bst = Node of 'a * 'b * ('a, 'b) bst * ('a, 'b) bst | Leaf
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you may get into trouble because `'a` needs a comparison operator. This is why in the standard library, the `Map` and `Set` modules are implemented as functors, so that it is possible to specify the comparison ordering.

If you decide to go along the `'a` polymorphism way, you'll have to use the "magical" default comparison operator `compare`.

The problem is different in F#, because there are ways to attach a comparison operator to a type.